# Adobe Forms - User Ability to Add New Fields

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I'm trying to create a fillable PDF form that allows a user to click a button to add new fields.
Basically, I want the user to be able to add a new set of fields to record details of a new person.

So if the default form has one 'person' set of fields (name, DOB, address), I want there to be an option to 'add another person', and fill out the same fields. The new fields would have to have a different value to the previous fields (e.g. name1, name2 etc).

Is this possible? How is it done?

Comment: You say "Adobe Forms" in your question title. Do you mean the native AcroForm PDF forms? Or do you mean the deprecated piggyback XFA forms?

Comment: Assuming it's an AcroForm, users with just Adobe Reader won't be able to execute code that adds fields even though that's possible with the JavaScript API. Instead, you'd create the extra fields, set them to be hidden, and then show them when necessary. If this sounds like what you want to do, I can craft an answer based on that method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.